# Codeigniter: Load model inside CI_Lang child class

Tags: codeigniter, instance

I'm using the i18n library written by Jérôme Jaglale: http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n

There, the languages are stored inside the library, in an array like this:

```
  // languages
  var $languages = array(
    'de' => 'german',
    'en' => 'english'
  );
```

What I'm trying to do, is get these languages from a database table, like this:

```
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model("language_model");
    $languages = $CI->language_model->find_all();

    ...
  }
```

But this gives an error, when trying to get the CI instance:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in .../system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

Any idea how I could get the CI instance in language library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the constructor function located? In what type of file and in what directory?

Comment: The file is /application/core/MY_Lang.php. It's the default MY_Lang file from the i18n library, plus the 3 lines I placed in the constructor.

Comment: The instance is already defined there. Simply use `$this->load->model()`

Comment: Doesn't work. Looks like the controller is loaded after the language class, so I'll have to figure another way to load the languages from database.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I didn't load the module at all.
I simply got the DB object and performed the query directly, like so:

```
$db =& DB();
$db->where('active', 1);
$languages = $db->get('language')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

no try this ..works for me

```
      $CI =& get_instance();

      $CI->load->database();
      $CI->load->model('language_model');
      $lang['welcome_txt_description']=$CI->language_model->get_site_description_language(5,'german');
```

From
Buddhika Perera >>>>>> SRI LANKA